# Forgot to add salt to my water softener - how many regens do I need?

Tags: water-softener

I am usually pretty good about remembering to add salt to my water softener, but the last couple months I have been extra distracted with life. I finally realized my water was feeling harder than usual, so I added a bag of salt (40 lbs) to the (empty) brine tank and set the softener to regen that night. The next day the water still feels harder than usual. Do I do another regen tonight, or do I need to "give it a couple days" for my water to get back to the usual softness? (My softener is set to regenerate every 7 days.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analytic solution: go buy some hardness test strips (pool and spa section) and keep running regens until it stops going down, or at least until it reaches an acceptable level.

You can also save a lot of money and effort by using test strips to monitor your hardness levels and adjusting regen rate so that it doesn't regen until hardness reaches moderate levels.